# TypeError Exception: no implicit conversion of Pathname into String when i make a get query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parse-platform, type-conversion

In my controller method, i am doing this

```
def update_item_category
    Parse.init :application_id => "appid",
        :api_key => "appkey",
        :quiet => true
    puts Parse::Query.new("Brands").eq("brand_id", "5").get
end
```

on ".get" i am getting "TypeError Exception: no implicit conversion of Pathname into String".
Please help me out.

Comment: Bug? https://github.com/opbeat/opbeat_ruby/issues/3